# Getting a regular List from a Type List

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, dependent-type

I've found a way to convert a `Nat` into an `Integer` using `Proxy` and `natVal` as you can see in the code below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Main where

import Data.Proxy (Proxy)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import GHC.TypeLits

main :: IO ()
main = do
  fromNat (undefined :: Proxy 5)

fromNat :: KnownNat n => Proxy n -> IO ()
fromNat proxy = do
  let (num :: Integer) = natVal proxy -- converting a Nat to an Integer
  putStrLn $ "Some num: " <> show num
```

But I'm not able to think a straightforward way to convert a type List into a regular list, the code below doesn't even type check:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Main where

import Data.Proxy (Proxy)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import GHC.TypeLits

main :: IO ()
main = do
  fromNat     (undefined :: Proxy 5)
  fromListNat (undefined :: Proxy '[2,3,10])

fromNat :: KnownNat n => Proxy n -> IO ()
fromNat proxy = do
  let (num :: Integer) = natVal proxy -- converting a Nat to an Integer
  putStrLn $ "Some num: " <> show num

fromListNat :: Proxy [Nat] -> IO ()
fromListNat = undefined
```

How can I convert a type list into a regular list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to make something like `KnownNat` but for type level lists of `Nat`. We proceed by induction on the type-level list, using a type class. This typeclass, through its superclass constraints, will check that all elements of you list satisfy `KnownNat` and then it will use that fact to reconstruct a term-level list.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, KindSignatures #-}

-- Similar to `KnownNat (n :: Nat)`
class KnownNatList (ns :: [Nat]) where
   natListVal :: proxy ns -> [Integer]

-- Base case
instance KnownNatList '[] where
  natListVal _ = []

-- Inductive step
instance (KnownNat n, KnownNatList ns) => KnownNatList (n ': ns) where
  natListVal _ = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n) : natListVal (Proxy :: Proxy ns)
```

Then, `fromListNat` takes the same shape as `fromNat`:

```
fromListNat :: KnownNatList ns => Proxy ns -> IO ()
fromListNat proxy = do
  let (listNum :: [Integer]) = natListVal proxy
  putStrLn $ "Some list of num: " <> show listNum
```

Splicing in these changes to your initial code, I get the expected output:

```
$ ghc Main.hs
$ ./Main
Some num: 5
Some list of num: [2,3,10]
```